# Extracting all rows based on a value of cell without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm really struggling to find an answer to this as online I've really only found VBA solutions to this problem which isn't what I wish to learn how to do.

**THE PROBLEM**

```
BLOOD NAME  AGE GENDER
A   David   18  Male
B   Sarah   22  Female
O   Lucy    32  Female
AB  Steven  23  Male
O   John    11  Male
B   Mike    25  Male
AB  Paul    24  Male
O   Amy 23  Female
B   Drake   22  Female
O   Linda   11  Female
```

Very simply from the above dataset I wish to recreate this range but filter for only select BLOOD TYPE O.

**MY ATTEMPTS**

Started with a VLookup table however that stops at the first occurrence of O. Then tried incorporating IF/THEN/ELSE logic into a MATCH operand trying to locate the row numbers outputting to an array. (not gonna post my failed attempts) I did find a similarish problem online however they solved it via referencing the range manually using ROW(A1), ROW(A2) etc etc wasn't what I after.

Really want to learn how to do this type of iterative selections using Excel formulae only.  Even if not solving the problem any direction towards resources where I can learn more about this type problem, would be still appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with autofilter?

Comment: Look into [advanced Filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KGqJLXJvgY).

Comment: Using the auto filter isn't always appropriate when attempting to automate particular work flows. I've seen people do this request function without the auto filter and I wish to learn how.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have said - No Filters.

Comment: The issue is that to do this will need to use Array Formulas, You will need so many that it will slow or even crash excel every time it recalculates.  How much data are we talking; 100s,1000s,10000s?

Comment: Here's an in depth explanation with an example workbook for you to play around with: http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/947848-lookup-a-value-and-return-multiple-results.html

Comment: `I've seen people do this request function without the auto filter and I wish to learn how` so study what they did?

Comment: @ScottCraner if you sort it first, then you can do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139040/index-match-sumproduct-multiple-rows-and-columns) yes?

Comment: @findwindow yes if sorted it can be done without array formulas.

Answer (score 9):

This does not use array formulas, but does use a *helper column*.  Assuming data in cols **A** through **D**, in **E2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="O",1+MAX($E$1:E1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Each of the **O** rows is marked with a simple sequential value.  This makes it easy for the usual *MATCH() / INDEX()* methods.

Pick some other cell and enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$E:$E,0)),"")
```

and copy this cell both across and down:

[image]

Comment: Found this example really interesting, thank you so much!

Comment: @JeffPalson  You are quite welcome......this technique can be applied to many cases requiring the extraction of specific rows from a table............the *helper column* can be crafted to handle multiple criteria from multiple columns!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with array formulas. It will calculate extremely slowly, and honestly VBA is a much better solution. You will need to tell excel these are array formulas by hitting "Ctrl + Shift + Enter" after inputting the formulas, this will add the {} around the equation. Finally, drag down the array formulas to see the first "X" results with blood type "O":

First cell formula for "Blood" --> assumes blood is in column A of sheet1
`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$D,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A:$A="O",ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),1,1),"")}`

First cell formula for "Name" --> assumes name is in column B of sheet1
`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$D,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A:$A="O",ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),2,1),"")}`

First cell formula for "Age" --> assumes age is in column c of sheet1
`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$D,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A:$A="O",ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),3,1),"")}`

First cell formula for "Gender" --> assumes gender is in column d of sheet1
`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$D,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A:$A="O",ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),4,1),"")}`

Results:

```
BLOOD   NAME    AGE GENDER
O       Lucy    32  Female
O       John    11  Male
O       Amy     23  Female
O       Linda   11  Female
```

Comment: This works for small sets of data.  If there is more than a few hundred it will crash excel. Also, FWIW when using array formulas one should avoid full column references, as it forces unneeded calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The following array formula can be put in row 2 (anywhere from column E onward) and copied across 3 columns and down as far as is necessary:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("O",$A$2:$A$11)),ROW($A$2:$A$11),""),ROW()-1)),"")`

This is entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and uses a fixed array (A2:A11). If your array is going to change size, you can make the reference to it dynamic by using `INDIRECT` and `COUNTA` so that it always encompasses the *used* range, like so:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("O",INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A)))),ROW(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A))),""),ROW()-1)),"")`

**What is happening:**

The `SEARCH` function is looking for "O"s, then the `IF` returns the row number if an "O" was found and nothing if no "O" was found.

The `SMALL` function is looking for the *n*th instance of the results returned by the `SEARCH` function, where *n* = `ROW()-1`.

The `INDEX` function returns the *n*th value from the array A:A, B:B, etc, where *n* = the row number returned by the `SMALL` function.

The `IFERROR` function is not necessary but it makes for a cleaner dataset, all it does is replace the formulas that didn't return anything useful with a blank instead.

Comment: wow, love this! thank you so much for the explanation found this fascinating and was able to learn loads from it!! Cheers man!! one thing though - using the search command when looking type for blood type A, it's included type AB also in the filter. Anyhow still loved this nonetheless!

Comment: That is a limitation, yes. You can avert it by substituting "AB" values for something else so that "A" is no longer a substring. Like this: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A)),"AB","C"))),ROW(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A))),""),ROW()-1)),"")`. You would need to remember to search for "C" when you want to return the "AB" results now. It's a bit hacky, but for a small, known, list (as is the case with blood types) it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this standard formula:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( A$2:A$11, AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
ROW($A:$A) / ( $A$2:$A$11 = "O" ), ROWS( $A$2:$A2 ) ) ), "" )
```

or if you want to limit the size of size of column `A`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( A$2:A$11, AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
ROW($A$1:$A$11) / ( $A$2:$A$11 = "O" ), ROWS( $A$2:$A2 ) ) ), "" )
```

Enter the formula in `G2` then copy it to `G2:J10`

[image]