# How to extract multiple rows that meet a criteria which is given by 2 drop-down lists in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
        A       |    B    |        C       |       D      |    E    |    F
1     NAME      |   TASK  |      ADRESS    | ORDER_GIVER  |  COUNT  |   NOTE

2   DROPDOWN_2  |   move  |  NY, xy_street |     Ann      |    1    |    ...

3   DROPDOWN_2  |   fill  |  CA, yx_street |    Rose      |    3    |    ...

... 

100   NAME      |   TASK  |      ADRESS    | ORDER_GIVER  |  COUNT  |   NOTE

101  DROPDOWN_1

102

103   NAME      |   TASK  |      ADRESS    | ORDER_GIVER  |  COUNT  |   NOTE

104  DROPDOWN_1
```

INITIALLY:

In rows 1-99 you find the tasks with 1 column empty (NAME). 
In rows 100+ you find "Tickets" which can be printed (2 rows for example 100-101)

THEN

1, The ORGANISER (me) makes tickets with names, by ctrl+c/ctrl+v the "ticket structure" and by choosing a name from the DROPDOWN_1 list.

2, Then starts to assign the tasks (row 1-99) to people by choosing them from the DROPDOWN_2 list. (note that  dropdown name lists contain the same names.)

After this I would like to have the Excel to fill in the tickets by the rows that contain the same name as the ticket. One person can be assigned to more tasks, but one task can only be assigned to one man. (So tickets can have 1 NAME but more rows depending on the 1-99 list.

I am asking you to help me make a formula or function for this "autofill" of tickets because I have been searching for days for a solution however couldn't find a proper one.
In the Similar problems and solutions section you can find 2 links which had the closest answer. Unfortunately neither of them contain dropdown lists. I tried to solve the problem with INDEX(MATCH()) functions, but the problem is that it cannot handle the changes of names.

Thanks you,
Max

---

Similar problems and solutions:

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/28/extract-all-rows-from-a-range-that-meet-criteria-in-one-column-in-excel/

[Extracting all rows based on a value of cell without VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506151/extracting-all-rows-based-on-a-value-of-cell-without-vba)

Comment: I am having a problem understanding exactly what you want, and where your problem lies.  To help me help you, I suggest you mock up a workbook that has sufficient data and demonstrates the problem; then upload that to a public sharing site (eg DropBox, OneDrive, etc) and post a link here.  My first thought would be to use the Advanced Filter, but I don't understand you setup well enough to advise further.

Answer (score 0):

Select `A101:F392` and enter this as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:F99,ROUND(MOD(SMALL(IFERROR(CHOOSE({1,2},SMALL(IFERROR(1/(1/MMULT(IF(SMALL(COUNTIF(A2:A99,"<="&A2:A99),ROW(INDIRECT("2:98")))=SMALL(COUNTIF(A2:A99,"<="&A2:A99),ROW(INDIRECT("1:97"))),0,ROW(A2:A98)),{1,1}))+{0.001,-0.001},FALSE),ROW(INDIRECT("1:196"))),COUNTIF(A2:A99,"<="&A2:A99)+ROW(A2:A99)/1000),FALSE),ROW(INDIRECT("1:292"))),1)*1000,0),{1,2,3,4,5,6}),"")
```