# Return a list of values based on criteria - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a `PRODUCT` sheet with 500 products listed. In the same workbook, I have a `DOCKET` sheet - a copy of which is sent with each persons order. I'd like to be able to `"Enable"` any number of rows on the `PRODUCT` sheet, and have them appear on the `DOCKET`.

[Product Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1o3J.png)

With the formula I'm currently using, I have to sort the `PRODUCT` list so that any of the lines I've `"Enabled"` are in the first few rows and it is tedious - `=IF(PRODUCTS!$A3="Enable",PRODUCTS!$C3,"")`

I'd like to be able to `"Enable"` a row anywhere in the `PRODUCT` list and have the value in `Column C` appear on the `DOCKET`.

I think I need to slot 'INDEX' in there somewhere but can't for the life of me work it out. Anyone know what formula I should use?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506151/extracting-all-rows-based-on-a-value-of-cell-without-vba it provides 2 different approaches for filtering.

Comment: Thanks bud. I tried searching for similar scenarios but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of products is not very high you can use something like this (enter into A2 of DOCKET sheet)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PRODUCT!C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(PRODUCT!A:A)/(PRODUCT!A:A="Enable"),ROW(A1))),"")
```

The main part is this

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(PRODUCT!A:A)/(PRODUCT!A:A="Enable"),ROW(A1))
```

which finds n-th lowest row number that has "Enable" in column A of Product sheet, where n is to tied to row number so it starts at 1 and increments by 1 each row.